# UNDIFINED INDEX PHP Notice: Undefined index: num_int in C:\xampp\htdocs\ferre-max\php\registro.php on line 14

Tags: php

HOLA ESTOY HACIENDO UN FORMULARIO DE ENVÍO PERO ME SALE ESTE ERROR

> Notice: Undefined index: num_int in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ferre-max\php\registro.php on line 14

ESTE ES EL CODIGO HTML

```
    <form class=" needs-validation col-md-6" action="php/registro.php" method="GET" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row ">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom01">Nombre : </label>
        <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="Mark" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor introduce tu nombre 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom02">Apellido : </label>
        <input name="apellido" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Otto Diaz" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor introduce tu apellido
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom03">E-mail : </label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Juan@example.com" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Por favor introduce tu email .
          </div>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            ✔ Bien
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom04">Contraseña :</label>
        <input name="pass" type="password" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="* * * * * * " required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escribe una contraseña
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom05">Sexo :</label>
        <select name="sexo" class="custom-select" id="validationCustom05">
          <option selected>Selecciona tu sexo</option>
          <option value="M">Masculino</option>
          <option value="F">Femenino</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor selecciona tu sexo
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">
        <label for="validationCustom06">Edad :</label>
        <input name="edad" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom06"required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escribe tu edad
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom0">Telefono</label>
        <input name="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom06" placeholder="55 415 857 15" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor inserte su número de telefono
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom07">Estado :</label>
        <select name="estado" class="custom-select" id="validationCustom07">
          <option selected>Selecciona tu Estado..</option>
          <option value="Aguas_Calientes">Aguas Calientes</option>
          <option value="Baja_California">Baja California</option>
          <option value="Baja_California Sur">Baja California Sur</option>
          <option value="Campeche">Campeche</option>
          <option value="CDMX">Ciudad de México</option>
          <option value="Chihuahua">Chihuahua</option>
          <option value="Chiapas">Chiapas</option>
          <option value="Coahuila">Coahuila</option>
          <option value="Colima">Colima</option>
          <option value="Durango">Durango</option>
          <option value="Guanajuato">Guanajuato</option>
          <option value="Guerrero">Guerrero</option>
          <option value="Hidalgo">Hidalgo</option>
          <option value="Jalisco">Jalisco</option>
          <option value="Estado_México">Estado de México</option>
          <option value="Michoacán">Michoacán</option>
          <option value="Morelos">Morelos</option>
          <option value="Nayarit">Nayarit</option>
          <option value="Nuevo_León">Nuevo_León</option>
          <option value="Oaxaca">Oaxaca</option>
          <option value="Puebla">Puebla</option>
          <option value="Querétaro">Querétaro</option>
          <option value="Quintana_Roo">Quintana Roo</option>
          <option value="San_Luis_Potosí">San Luis Potosí</option>
          <option value="Sinaloa">Sinaloa</option>
          <option value="Sonora">Sonora</option>
          <option value="Tabasco">Tabasco</option>
          <option value="Tamaulipas">Tamaulipas</option>
          <option value="Tlaxcala">Tlaxcala</option>
          <option value="Veracruz">Veracruz</option>
          <option value="Yucatán">Yucatán</option>
          <option value="Zacatecas">Zacatecas</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor selecciona tu Estado
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom08">Delegación o Municipio</label>
        <input name="delegacion" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom08" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor Escriba su delegación
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom09">Colonia</label>
        <input name="colonia" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom09" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escriba su colonia
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom10">Calle </label>
        <input name="calle" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom10" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escriba su calle
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom12">Num Exterior : </label>
        <input name="num_ext" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom12" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escriba su Num Exterior
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom11">Num Interior :</label>
        <input name="num_int" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom11" placeholder="" >
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escriba su número interior
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom12">Codigo Postal * </label>
        <input name="cod_post" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom12" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Por favor escriba su número postal
        </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          ✔ Bien
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
          Acepta nuestros Términos y Condiciones .
        </label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Acepte nuestra politica de terminos y condiciones 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Registrarse ! </button>
  </form>
```

ESTE ES EL CODIGO PHP y el nombre de mi registro en php es registro.php

```
    <?php
    $nom=$_GET["nombre"];
    $ape=$_GET["apellido"];
    $email=$_GET["email"];
    $pass=$_GET["pass"];
    $sexo=$_GET["sexo"];
    $edad=$_GET["edad"];
    $telef=$_GET["telefono"];
    $estado=$_GET["estado"];
    $del=$_GET["delegacion"];
    $col=$_GET["colonia"];
    $calle=$_GET["calle"];
    $num_ext=$_GET["num_ext"];
    $num_int=$_GET["num_int"];
    $cod_post=$_GET["cod_post"];
    require("conexion_db.php");
    // CONECTANDO A LA BASE DE DATOS
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$usuario,$pass);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ){
        echo "Error en la conexión a la Base de Datos";
        exit();
   }
   //especificamos la base de datos con que queremos trabajar pide conexion 
   y base de datos que queremos trabajar
   mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la base 
   de datos");
   // UTLIZAMOS EL UTF-8 PARA QUE NOS ACEPTE CARACATERES LATINOS 
  mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
  //Insertamos el query que queremos que haga al momento de que presione 
  SUBMIT
  $consulta="INSERT INTO cliente (nombre,
  apellido,
  sexo,
  edad,
  email,
  clave,
  telefono,
  id_estado_1,
  id_delegacion_1,
  id_colonia_1,
  id_calle_1,
  num_ext,
  num_int,
  cod_post) VALUES ('$nom','$ape','$sexo','$edad','$email'
  ,'$pass','$telef','$estado','$del','$col',
  '$calle','$num_ext','$num_int','$cod_post')";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
  if ($resultado==false) {
    echo "Error . Intenta Nuevamente";
  }else{
    echo "Registro Exitoso";
  }

 //CERRAMOS LA BASE DE DATOS PARA QUE NO ME CONSUMA RECURSOS
 mysqli_close($conexion);
 ?>
```

Comment: Estas haciendo alguna validacion?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el inspector del navegador para debug (click derecho, opcion  *inspeccionar elemento*. Dirigite a la pestaña **RED** y observa los parametros que son enviados por **GET**  cuando presionas el boton subtmit

Comment: El error que te genera, es que le esta faltando uno de los parametros, cuando intentas acceder a un elemento, te genera dicho error. Tambien, puedes ir comentando (en el archivo php) las lineas que accedes al GET para ver cual falla. Mucha suerte

Answer (score 1):

Una observación:
En el HTML, el input name="num_int" no es un campo requerido como los demás, tienes:

```
<input name="num_int" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom11" placeholder="">
```

Está la posibilidad que no se rellene ese input y llegue vacío, y en la base de datos ese campo no acepte valores vacíos...

Si no quieres modificar el atributo de la base de datos, añádele el atributo required al html para que no se de la posibilidad de que se envíe vacío, quedaría:

```
<input name="num_int" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom11" placeholder="" required>
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias mi amigo